# What is the name of this property of relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, relations

What is the name of property of a binary relation $R$ that states that $\lnot(a\mathrel{R} b) \iff \lnot(b \mathrel{R} a)$ for all $a, b$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we can remove the negation because this is an if and only if. Therefore this is the same as saying $a\mathrel{R}b\iff b\mathrel{R}a$.

This property is called symmetry, and such $R$ is called a symmetric relation.

Comment: Thanks. I was getting confused because of the negations.

Comment: Yes, it's easy to get confused with negations. But a handy trick to remember is that $p\iff q$ is itself equivalent to $\lnot p\iff\lnot q$, so we can remove the negations in that case.

Comment: You could also use $aRb \implies bRa$.